# Can I make MySQL trigger events more detailed?

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner with MySQL. I want to create a trigger with a more specific condition (specific statement) than just INSERT, UPDATE, DROP, etc. For example, I would like something like the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name AFTER UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'P' WHERE column2 = 'Q' FOR EACH ROW UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 42 WHERE column2 = 66;
```

Where `AFTER UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 'P' WHERE column2 = 'Q'` would be the trigger event and `UPDATE table2 SET column1 = 42 WHERE column2 = 66` would be the trigger action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the old and new values for an `UPDATE` via the `old` and `new` pseudo rows. Of course you can use them in your logic.

```
CREATE TRIGGER name
               AFTER UPDATE
                     ON table1
               FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.column1 = 'P'
     AND old.column2 = 'Q' THEN
    UPDATE table2
           SET column1 = 42
           WHERE column2 = 66;
  END IF;
END;
```